# PlayFrameWork SQL tutorial?

Tags: java, playframework

i am new in playframework i know how to install playframework and connect it to the database . Is there is any tutorial for that like how to perform sql operation using java in playframework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is not dependent on the Play Framework; it's dependent on the database you choose to use as a store for your Play Framework application.

[W3 Schools has a pretty good tutorial for basic SQL operations](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/).  You can also look up additional commands and functionality provided by your specific database provider in the docs for that database.  e.g. look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/) if you've chosen to use a version of PostgreSQL

The problem is confused slightly in that what I think you need is a method for your application to map rich application objects to flat database tables.  This task can be done using an Object-Relationship-Mapping or functional-mapping tool.  Ebean is an example of an ORM and Slick is an example of a functional mapping tool, both of which can be used in Play applications by adding their drivers to your /project/build.scala file in the list of your project dependencies.

Setting up Ebean for your Java-based  Play project is covered on the page of the Play 2.1 Java tutorial after the one linked to by bistros -  [Using the Ebean ORM](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaEbean)

Comment: lol, I hadn't seen that site before, thanks for the link.  That said, I don't think those arguments really apply to SQL, W3Schools only cover the core functionality (as far as I can see) and SQL's been around long enough that it's core is stable.  Funnily, I realize now that if I'm unsure of a command, I usually end up looking at the w3school reference to get in the park and then look up Postgres's docs to get the canonical reference. You've always got to CYA.

Answer (score 1):

see playframework.com tutorial page.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Installing
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaDatabase

Comment: Thanx for Answer on my question sir i know how to install connect to the database but i need tutorial for sql operation

Comment: @simmant So go on and learn SQL. Buy a book about relational databases. It's a worthwile skill to have. But this has nothing to do with Play. Or if you're on the cheap, search for a tutorial. There's enough material out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can start direct with examples from the website. I think this one is very nice to understand how to work with database.

[play-java-ebean-example](https://example.lightbend.com/v1/download/play-java-ebean-example)

Comment: Thank you for the such nice tutorial, but its been long back I asked this question :). This will be helpful for other folks, who is having same query/concern.